# How could I use specific colors to a combined plotly visualization in R?

Tags: r, colors, plotly

I have two `data.frame` as follows:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  week = c(rep(1, times = 3), rep(2, times = 3)),
  cat = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), times = 2),
  count = round(runif(6, 1, 10))
)
```

and

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  week = c(rep(1, times = 2), rep(2, times = 2)),
  cat = rep(c("E", "F"), times = 2),
  count = round(runif(4, 1, 10))
)
```

and the plotly code is

```
plotly::plot_ly(df1,x = ~week, y = ~count, type = "bar", split = ~cat) %>%
  add_trace(data = df2,x = ~week, y = ~count, type = "scatter", 
            mode = "lines", split = ~cat, yaxis = 'y2') %>%
  layout(title = 'Title',
         xaxis = list(title = ""),
         yaxis = list(side = 'left', title = 'var1', showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE),
         yaxis2 = list(side = 'right', overlaying = "y",
                       title = 'var2', showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE),
         showlegend = FALSE)
```

But I am not able to specify specific colors to each group (A, B, C, E and F). I was trying to use `color = ~cat, colors = c(A = "red", B = "green", C = "yellow")` for bar plot and similarly for line plot. But somehow it's not working though it's working if I only work with bar plot or line plot.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's advisable to define the colors in the `plot_ly` call and then add bars and lines with the `col = ~cat` argument. See below:

```r
plotly::plot_ly(colors = c("A" = "red", "B" = "green", "C" = "yellow", "E" = "blue", "F" = "darkgreen")) %>% 
    add_bars(data = df1, x = ~week, y = ~count, type = "bar", color = ~cat) %>%
    add_trace(data = df2,x = ~week, y = ~count, type = "scatter", 
              mode = "lines", color = ~cat, yaxis = 'y2') %>%
    layout(title = 'Title',
           xaxis = list(title = ""),
           yaxis = list(side = 'left', title = 'var1', showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE),
           yaxis2 = list(side = 'right', overlaying = "y",
                         title = 'var2', showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE),
           showlegend = FALSE)
```

[image: Combined bar/line plot]

Comment: I want to specify colors for each category A, B, C, D, E and F. So I want to specify colors for lines also.